# is there a universal way to work with arrays of primitives and arrays of non-primitives in java?

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

I understand that for every primitive type in java there is a reference type that can represent the same values, plus null. For example, int and java.lang.Integer.

I also understand that while all arrays (even java.lang.Object[]) derive from java.lang.Object, only arrays of non-primitive types can be converted to java.lang.Object[].

In other words, we can do:

```
Class type = Integer.class;
Object[] o = (Object[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(type, 4);
```

but the following results in an exception:

```
Class type = int.class;
Object[] o = (Object[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(type, 4);
```

so in that particular case we could do:

```
 Class type = int.class;
 Object o = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(type, 4);
```

...which seems fine, until one wonders how to add elements to an Object that represents an array that cannot be converted to Object[].

is the only way around this problem to check the type of the elements of the array and cast the Object as appropriate?

ie:

```
  if (type == int.class)
  ((int[])o)[0] = getFirstElement();

  else if (type == short.class)
  ((short[])o[0] = getFirstElement();
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: No, there is no general way to deal with primitive arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides creating arrays, `java.lang.reflect.Array` also offers methods to get and set elements in arrays:

```
Class<?> type = int.class;
Object array = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(type, 4);

int index = 0;
Object value = getFirstElement();
java.lang.reflect.Array.set(array, index, value);
```

Also note from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#set%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29) that the value `is first automatically unwrapped if the array has a primitive component type.`  So this should work for any array, including those that do not inherit from `Object[]`.

There is a corresponding `Object get(Object array, int index)` method too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the first case you can assign to Object and then use `isInstanceOf Object[]` to see if you have an array of Object.

But ultimately you have to have some sort of conditional operation to do element access/assignment.  Thankfully there are only (IIRC) 7 different scalar data types.

(The language spec could have defined the Integer/Float/et al to include array member access methods -- eg, Integer would define get and set methods for `int[]`.  But they didn't.  At best you could define wrappers for the (alas, final) Number subclasses to define these methods.)